# How to scroll 2 different panels independently?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

So I have 2 panels side by side that scroll via up and down buttons.

At the moment both panels are scrolling up and down at the same time and what I need is to make them completely independent.

[**See DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tiaggo/emka1b6n/4/)

Thank you!

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper-left">
<div class="news-container">
    <div class="news-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="down">down</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-right">
<div class="products-container">
    <div class="products-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="up2">Up</a>
<a href="#" id="down2">down</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.news-content, .products-content').height() > $('.news-container, .products-container').height()) {
        $("#down, #down2").hover(function () {
            animateContent("down");
        }, function() { $('.news-content, .products-content').stop(); });

        $("#up").hover(function () {
            animateContent("up");
        }, function() { $('.news-content, .products-content').stop(); });
    }
});
function animateContent(direction) {  
    var animationOffset = $('.news-container, .products-container').height() - $('.news-content, .products-content').height();
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }
    $('.news-content, .products-content').animate({ "marginTop": animationOffset + "px" }, "1500");
}
$('html').on('click','a.up, a.down, a.up2, a.down2',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sgroves said, you are calling animate on both divs.

To fix it, you need to bind the products scrolling separately from the news-scrolling.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mobabur94/emka1b6n/6/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bindEvents('news');
    bindEvents('products');
});

function bindEvents(prefix) {
    if ($('.' + prefix + '-content').height() > $('.' + prefix + '-container').height()) {
        $('#' + prefix + '-down').hover(function () {
            animateContent(prefix, 'down');
        }, function () {
            $('.' + prefix + '-content').stop();
        });
        $('#' + prefix + '-up').hover(function () {
            animateContent(prefix, 'up');
        }, function () {
            $('.' + prefix + '-content').stop();
        });
    }
}

function animateContent(prefix, direction) {
    var animationOffset = $('.' + prefix + '-container').height() - $('.' + prefix + '-content').height();
    if (direction == 'up') {
        animationOffset = 0;
    }
    $('.' + prefix + '-content').animate({
        'marginTop': animationOffset + 'px'
    }, '1500');
}
```

I also modified your html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="news-container">
        <div class="news-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        </div>
    </div> <a href="#" id="news-up">Up</a>
 <a href="#" id="news-down">down</a>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="products-container">
        <div class="products-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>

        </div>
    </div> <a href="#" id="products-up">Up</a>
 <a href="#" id="products-down">down</a>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.wrapper {
    float:left;
    padding: 10px;
}
.news-container, .products-container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.news-content {
    background:#61DAED;
}
.products-content {
    background:#EDC261;
}
a#news-up, a#news-down {
    color: red;
}
a#products-up, a#products-down {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `animate` on both divs:

```
$('.news-content, .products-content').animate({ "marginTop": animationOffset + "px" }, "1500");
```

This will animate both divs no matter which link you hover on. You only want to animate one div at a time. One way to do this is to pass the class of the div you want to animate to `animateContent`:

```
$("#down, #down2").hover(function() {
    var classSelector;

    if (this.id == "down") {
        classSelector= '.news-content';
    } else {
        classSelector= '.products-content';
    }

    animateContent(classSelector, 'down');
}, function() {
    var classSelector;

    // you'll notice this is a bunch of repeated code.
    // perhaps you can find a way to clean it up?
    if (this.id == "down") {
        classSelector = '.news-content';
    } else {
        classSelector = '.products-content';
    }

    $(classSelector).stop();
});
```

Then in `animateContent`:

```
function animateContent(classSelector, direction) {
    // use classSelector in your jQuery selectors here
}
```

There are much simpler ways of doing this, by the way, but I wanted to give an example that builds on your existing code.

Comment: I couldn't make it work for some reason. Do you think you could do a Fiddle with your example? Thank you!

Comment: @tiago what errors are you getting? what's going wrong? you're not going to have someone to write code for you all the time. might as well learn to debug yourself.

Comment: Well, I basically copied your JS code to my example and it didn't work.

Comment: you have to do a little more than that. my code was meant to help you fix your code, not replace your code.

Comment: I don't understand this bit here:  // use classSelector in your jQuery selectors here

Comment: @tiago i have no idea why i couldn't fork your fiddle. here's a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fopejeca/1/edit

Comment: @mobabur94 while helpful, that fiddle has nothing to do with my answer. you should post your own answer, and i'll upvote it :)